# Make a GIS map searchable on ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing

I have a georeferenced photo image. Each point in the map corresponds to the exact latitude/longitude on the ground. The map also has names of cities but I can't use those names for searching.

Is there any way that I can make the map searchable such that, if I want to pan/zoom to a certain portion of the map, just the name of the city/county or state would be enough.

Right now, I am first using Google maps to find the area and later in ArcGIS.

Comment: Have you tried the Find tool?

Comment: Are you trying to search the georeferenced image? You won't have any luck doing that as it's a raster.

Comment: You can try to create bookmarks but you'll have to search for the cities at least once. Also you could find an online shp with cities, load it to the project and issue is solved. Fetzer is right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: The second tab of the find tool provide access to geocoding service online, so the more effective way to search places is to use such services, if the gazetteer in your area of interest is sufficient. Since it is not the case in my country, this option was not considered in the initial answer, which can provide help for those in the less lucky area.

**Original Post:**

As Fezter commented, you cannot search a raster map by name of cities in it.

If you want to, try digitizing your georeferenced map of cities to a point feature class. To do this, you should create a new feature class in a geodatabase (.gdb) or just [create](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/creating-a-new-shapefile.htm) a shapefile (.shp).

After creating the feature class or shapefile, and before you create points, you may like to create a name field for this feature class. Right click on the layer in TOC, then select open attribute table. In the table dock, click on the first button on the top left of it, then add field. You may name it and choose its type as text.

After setting up the name field, you can select start editing from the Editing toolbar or right click menu of the layer in TOC. Then you'll be able to create points by clicking on the points in your map (for details, see https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/07/28/getting-started-with-creating-features-in-arcgis-10/ ). And edit the name field according to your raster map.

When everything is done, save edits and stop editing. Then you can search your cities by the [Find tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-the-find-tool.htm) mentioned in another comment, or by [Select by attribute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm) tool in Selection menu.

Comment: As it was already georeferenced, the find tool panned/zoomed to the exact location.

Comment: @pnkjmndhl Cool. To clarify, you may mean the second tab of "location" in the Find tool, and I've updated my answer. The geocoding is not always available or sufficient in all areas around the world, therefore I kept the contents about the workflow with tedious manual labor.